# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory for different opening types

Tags: python

I have two almost similar ways to open a file:

first one works fine:

```
filename = 'RN6531_flat_20ums_3.pr'


pr_file = open(filename,'r')

print(pr_file.readlines())

pr_file = pr_file.close
```

the second one should do the same

```
filename = 'RN6531_flat_20ums_3.pr'

with open('filename') as pr_file:

    print(pr_file.readlines())

pr_file = pr_file.close
```

but actually delivers the error message

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'filename'
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm learning coding with python at the moment and don't see the difference. The paths are the same, the file exists, but only one way works as expected.

Comment: `open('filename')` -> `open(filename)`.

Comment: Also, due to how context managers in python work, you don't actually need to close the file after the `with` block

Comment: What Avery said. However, `pr_file = pr_file.close` doesn't actually close anything, it just binds the file's close method to the name `pr_file`. You need to call that method to close the file manually: `pr_file.close()`

Answer (score 0):

Fix some typo, also you don't have to close file manually context manager will do it for you

```py
filename = 'RN6531_flat_20ums_3.pr'

with open(filename, 'r') as pr_file:
    print(pr_file.readlines())
```